# How do I properly include an IIF Statement in a Dynamic SQL Statement without getting an Error

Tags: t-sql, dynamic, iif

The code I have below was working, it was creating more code that created code that set-up the extended properties for a given table.  But we wanted to start pulling pre-existing column descriptions from another table if there was a match.  I did that with a left join and a IIF statement, which works fine in a pure SQL statement.  BUT when I port it over into the Dynamic SQL version of the statement I get an error in the line with the IIF statement.

The error message is:

**Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 75
The data types nvarchar(max) and sql_variant are incompatible in the add operator.**

```
DECLARE @SProcAdd varchar(100) = 'sys.sp_addextendedproperty'
DECLARE @SProcUpdate varchar(100) = 'sys.sp_updateextendedproperty'
DECLARE @SQLTableAdd varchar(max) = ''
DECLARE @SQLColumnAdd varchar(max) = ''
DECLARE @SQLTableUpdate varchar(max) = ''
DECLARE @SQLColumnUpdate varchar(max) = ''
DECLARE @Table varchar(200) = 'Table_Name_Here'

SELECT  
@SQLColumnAdd =  CONCAT(@SQLColumnAdd + ' ' + CHAR(13) + '--*** COLUMN NAME: ' + ' ' + sysc.COLUMN_NAME + '   ' +
    '***********************************************************************************' 
    + CHAR(13) + 'EXEC ' + @SProcAdd + ' 
     @level0type=N''SCHEMA'', @level0name=N''' + a.TABLE_SCHEMA + ''' --assigns schema
    ,@level1type=N''TABLE'', @level1name=N''' + a.TABLE_NAME + ''' --assigns table
    ,@level2type=N''COLUMN'', @level2name=N''' + sysc.COLUMN_NAME + ''' --assigns column
    ,@name=N''DESCRIPTION'', @value=N''' + IIF(mcd.ColumnDescription = NULL,'Enter_Description_Here', mcd.ColumnDescription) + ''' -- <------------------------ UPDATE COLUMN DESCRIPTION HERE!' + CHAR(13) + '', '')
FROM OUR_SERVER.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES a
INNER JOIN OUR_SERVER.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS sysc on a.TABLE_NAME=sysc.TABLE_NAME 
LEFT JOIN OUR_SERVER.MetaPERC.MasterColumnDescription mcd on sysc.COLUMN_NAME = mcd.ColumnName
WHERE a.TABLE_NAME LIKE @Table
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION

PRINT @SQLColumnAdd
```

This is the old version of the code without the IIF statement that DOES work:

```
SELECT  
@SQLColumnAdd =  CONCAT(@SQLColumnAdd + ' ' + CHAR(13) + '--*** COLUMN NAME: ' + ' ' + sysc.COLUMN_NAME + '   ' +
    '***********************************************************************************' 
    + CHAR(13) + 'EXEC ' + @SProcAdd + ' 
     @level0type=N''SCHEMA'', @level0name=N''' + a.TABLE_SCHEMA + ''' --assigns schema
    ,@level1type=N''TABLE'', @level1name=N''' + a.TABLE_NAME + ''' --assigns table
    ,@level2type=N''COLUMN'', @level2name=N''' + sysc.COLUMN_NAME + ''' --assigns column
    ,@name=N''DESCRIPTION'', @value=N'' CASE WHEN mcd.ColumnDescription = NULL THEN ''Enter_Description_Here'' ELSE mcd.ColumnDescription END'' -- <------------------------ UPDATE COLUMN DESCRIPTION HERE!' + CHAR(13) + '', '')
FROM OUR_SERVER.[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES] a
INNER JOIN OUR_SERVER.[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS] sysc on a.TABLE_NAME=sysc.TABLE_NAME 
LEFT JOIN OUR_SERVER.MetaPERC.MasterColumnDescription mcd on sysc.COLUMN_NAME = mcd.ColumnName
WHERE a.TABLE_NAME LIKE @Table
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
```

Comment: I, assume, `ColumnDescription` is a `sql_variant`? You can't just concatenate that data type to a string based value, you need to *explicitly* convert it to the correct data type.

Comment: You may also want to avoid the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views. Aaron has an article here: https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views which goes into detail on why.
Similarly you may want to consider using a `CASE` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 expression instead of an `IIF`.

Comment: Aside: `mcd.ColumnDescription = NULL`? See [`equals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/equals-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#remarks) and [`is null`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/is-null-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: Regarding `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, I think there are various opinions regarding blanket avoidance. While it is true that it provides an incomplete view of everything that can be defined in SQL server, it has enough information to satisfy the basic needs of many dynamic SQL use cases and is often more convenient to use than the the sys tables.  If it has the required information for the purpose, I see no problem with its use.

Comment: On counting the quotes, it appears the the CASE statement in the original version was a part of the generated dynamic SQL (possibly part of a quoted string value therein), while the replacement IIF() in the new version is evaluated during dynamic SQL generation, with the result merged into the dynamic SQL as a quoted string. (This doesn't fix the issue, but may explain why the old version "worked".)

Comment: The CASE and IIF() might be better replaced with an ISNULL() or COALESCE(). Combined with the CAST suggestion earlier, the answer might be `'... @value=N''' + COALESCE(CAST(mcd.ColumnDescription AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 'Enter_Description_Here') + ''' ...'`.

Comment: Better yet, use the `QUOTENAME()` function to protect against syntax-breaking quote characters in the injected description - `'... @value=N' + QUOTENAME(COALESCE(CAST(mcd.ColumnDescription AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 'Enter_Description_Here'), '''') + ' ...'`. The `QUOTENAME()` function will both provide the outer quotes and will double-up and quotes contained within the description text. Note the removal of the quotes from the surrounding strings. The surrounding text still provides the "N" prefix.